# why is this character matching not working in r?

Tags: r

```
apple_orange<-readline(prompt="Enter your fruit: ")
  while((apple_orange!="apple")||(apple_orange!="orange"))
  {
    apple_orange<-readline(prompt="Enter your fruit: ")
  }
```

It keeps on Looping even when I type apple or orange .. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: emphasis made me lol. do you want `&` instead of `||`? a good way to tell what is going on is to set `apple_orange` to something and run each of the conditions individually, together, and then see what happens when you run the loop. you should be able to guess at that point But I think you need to read the differences among `&`,`&&`,`|`, and `||`

Answer (score 1):

Your condition says to keep the loop going if `apple_orange` != "apple" OR `apple_orange` != "orange". One of those conditions will always be true, making the overall condition true, so the loop keeps going. Just change the OR to an AND.